# "ubuntu-drivers devices" aplay traceback dump

Tags: drivers

`ubuntu-drivers` has something off here. What to do?

```
$ ubuntu-drivers devices
ERROR:root:could not open aplay -l
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/detect/sl-modem.py", line 35, in detect
    aplay = subprocess.Popen(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1704, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'aplay'
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this using `sudo apt-get install alsa-utils` that provides aplay